# spring-data-elasticsearch _mget with several indexes

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible with spring-data-elasticsearch to use [Multi get](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html) with several indexes?

There is a method ElasticsearchOperations#multiGet which accept a list of indexes, thus looks like only the first one is used.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible. Although `IndexCoordinates` might contain multiple index names, in many cases only the first is used. To use the list of indices the length of the list would need to be the same as the number of ids to retrieve. But currently the implementation uses `IndexCoordinates.getIndexName()` to set the index for each item.